# Azure self DNS server

Tags: azure, domain-name-system

I´m trying to install and configure this scenario:

1. Azure VM called DnsVM.
2. Azure VM called WebVM. (this one, haves 10 webpages on IIS, not a problem)

What i´m trying to do without success is to configure my first VM as DNS Server, not for outgoing request, but for Incoming request... like godaddy or DnSimple does.

So my questions are:

1. How do you configure DNS VM to work like DNS Server (for incoming requests)?
2. How do you configure this DNS server to point "contoso.com" to second VM into a specific port (5555)

I readed half of internet forums and didn´t find a correct answer about this problem. 
I hope anyone can help me here!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. There's nothing special about setting up a DNS server for internal vs. external. Maybe the only difference is that you probably don't want an AD integrated DNS server. HOWEVER, I strongly recommend against doing this. Running an internet-facing DNS server is not a good idea.
2. You don't. DNS doesn't deal with ports, only IP addresses.